# Hap video with avi format

Tags: video, codec, openframeworks

I'm trying to work with this openframeworks add-on to play a video with alpha : https://github.com/secondstory/ofxDSHapVideoPlayer
It needs a Hap video with avi format, I've had worked with Hap videos with mov format and could convert existing file with quicktime to Hap. But here these guys at renderheads have done something to make Hap format for avi files : http://renderheads.com/product/hap-for-directshow/
The problem is I don't get how I can convert my videos to this avi hap.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using ffmpeg to convert a hap movie with a quicktime container (.mov) to an avi container for use with the renderheads directshow playback filter.   You can simply use

```
ffmpeg -i inputMovie.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy outputMovie.avi
```

The best thing is that it doesn't need to re-encode the movie so you don't loose any quality and it converts it really quickly.   It doesn't work with all my movies though for which I'm still trying to figure out why.

Comment: I think the user is trying to use the `hap-for-directshow` but he doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, he mentions that he's made haps as mov's before but "The problem is I don't get how I can convert my videos to this avi hap" - the above method I posted will do just that, convert a hap movie with a mov container into a hap avi suitable for use with the renderheads directshow hap player